# How to add existing XML definitions to R.anim

Tags: android, android-animation, android-xml

Basically, I'm trying to create an effect using

android.R.anim.slide_in_right & android.R.anim.slide_out_left

However, only

android.R.anim.slide_in_left & android.R.anim.slide_out_right

appear to be readily available options.  I can see in android.jar, in res.anim, that there exist slide_in_right.xml and slide_out_left.xml, as well as many other definitions that don't appear to be readily defined for use.  My question is how can I add these definitions to android.R.anim so that I will be able to reference them in java?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you're talking about. What do you want to add to android.R.anim? (Btw just a tip, you can't add something to the android-intern framework R.java file.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy this xml in res/anim

**slide_in_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

**slide_out_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-50%p"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

You can now access animations by using R.anim.slide_in_right or R.anim.slide_out.left

Comment: ok, it didn't sink in until looking at this for a while and considering what Ahmad said before i understood that i actually have to create an anim folder in res.  once i did that, this all made sense.  thanks a lot for the help!